# Share one ssl certificate between multiples vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have a setup like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.104:80>
    ServerName domain1
    DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.104:80>
    ServerName domain2
    DocumentRoot /home/domain2/public_html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.104:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/domain3/public_html
    ServerName domain3
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.104:443>
    ServerName domain3
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/share/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/share/ssl/private/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/share/ssl/certs/bundle.cabundle
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to use `domain3` certificate in the other domains, preferably without having to repeat all the `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.104:443>` config.

In other words I want something like this: If the vhost has no explicit ssl config use cert for `domain3` (/usr/share/ssl/certs/certificate.crt)

Notes:

1.- I for sure will be setting more vhosts in the future

2.- I know (and don't care) of the ssl warnings the browser will show (hostname mismatch)

If this possible? how?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, the mis-matched certificate and hostnames are the reason this is not a feature in Apache. You will have to copy and paste the code for the ssl certs in order to use them for each Virtual Host.

Beyond getting separate certificates, I would recommend using multiple virtual host config files. Each file would be specific to a virtual host, and you can call the individual files easily via the main Apache config file with the "Include" directive.